# RewriteCond scope

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to test if file exists for both the rules at the bottom, but it only seems to work for the first one. The second rule would wrongly match my /style.css file and display the php page instead of style.css.

Isn't it supposed to test if file exists for all next rules until the `[L]` flag ?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ browse_folder.php?username=$1&folder=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ browse_user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

If I repeat the file_exists test before each of the two lines it works as expected.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ browse_folder.php?username=$1&folder=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ browse_user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 4):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to next `RewriteRule`. You can make a separate rule to skip all files and directories on top of other rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ browse_folder.php?username=$1&folder=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ browse_user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. The `[L.QSA]` is a typo ?

Comment: Thanks for catching, yes indeed a typo.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't keep up, I moved to another project while trying to fix this, if I switch back I will test.

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't it supposed to test if file exists for all next rules until the
>   [L] flag ?

No, it's not. `RewriteCond`'s are applied to the very first-next `RewriteRule` *only*. From the [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition. One or more
>   RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is
>   then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its
>   pattern, and if these conditions are met.

Note the `can precede` **a** `RewriteRule`

## Workaround

If you don't want to repeat yourself, you can proceed as following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Don't touch existing files/folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Those rules are only applied to non-existing files/folders
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ browse_folder.php?username=$1&folder=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ browse_user.php?username=$1 [L]
```